# Efficiently get n random documents from a Whoosh index

Tags: python, whoosh

Given a large [Whoosh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Whoosh/) index, how can I efficiently retrieve `n` random documents from it?

I can do this horribly inefficiently just by pulling all the documents into memory and using [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample)...

```
random.sample(list(some_index.searcher().documents()), n)
```

but that will be horribly inefficient (in terms of memory usage and disk IO) if the index contains a large number of documents.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new numeric field `ID` that should be unique and preferably auto-increment. Whoosh has not auto-increment , you should do it yourself.

Then to get your random list, just generate a list of random integers using `random.randint(1, MAX_ID)` than build a search query `"ID:2 or ID:16 or ID:43 or ..."` and use it for querying , you will get your desired list.

You can query an interval without knowing the max limit or the min limit. for example:

- `ID:[ 10 to ]`
- `ID:[ to 10]`
- `ID:[ 1 to 10]`
- `ID:2`
- `ID:2 | ID:3`

Comment: Hmm... Whoosh has auto-incrementing IDs, and the ability to query the maximum value of an ID property? I'm not too familiar with Whoosh, but I've never come across either such feature; I don't find anything Googling for `whoosh autoincrement` and I don't see anything like a `Max()` class in the [`query`](https://whoosh.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/query.html) docs. Could you add some more detail or links to this answer?

Comment: Whoosh don't have auto-increment , you should do it yourself. and Yes you can query something without knowing the max limit or the min limit. for example: `ID:[ 10 to ]` or `ID:[ to 10]` or  `ID:[ 1 to 10]` or `ID:2` or `ID:2 | ID:3'

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way, but what worked for me in similar situations was assigning a random number to every document while indexing. Every document gets a field named `rand_id` with a random number. You can then generate another random number `x` at the time of searching and search for `rand_id > x`. You can then limit the search to `n` items. If the search didn't yield enough results, search again for `rand_id < x` and take the rest.